# Any formula to find the maximum $n$th power of $x$ contained in a number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there any formula to find the maximum $n$th power of $x$ contained in a number?

Say I need to find $n$ where $x$ is $2$ and the number is $25$.

So the answer must be $4$.

The problem statement is to find $n$ where $x^n \le m$ and $x^{n+1} > m$, where $x,m,n$ are all positive integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking for the maximum $n$, such that for some base $x$ and some number $y$, we have:

$$x^{n}\leq y$$

By definition of the logarithm we have:

$$n\leq \log_{x}(y)$$

And as we want the smallest integral value of $n$, we can use the floor function, $\left\lfloor n\right\rfloor$, which is the greatest integer value below $n$. Therefore:

$$n=\left\lfloor \log_{x}(y) \right\rfloor$$

---

So for instance, using your example, where $x=2$ and $y=25$ we have:

$$n=\left\lfloor\log_{2}(25)\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor4.6438\dots\right\rfloor=4$$

Which is the answer you expected.

Comment: Thank you Shaktal, that is working awesome!!

Comment: And $\log_xy=\ln y/\ln x$.

Comment: ...of course, you don't necessarily have to use $\ln$; if your computing environment works in base-$b$ arithmetic, then there should be a base-$b$ logarithm function that is built-in, which you can then use.

Comment: Although note that after restating the equation as $x^n \le y$ this is really just a notational trick.